# How randomly accessing small constant arrays from CUDA kernel works

Tags: cuda, gpu

My kernel uses `float` array of size 8 by 8 with random access pattern below.

```
// inds - big array of indices in range 0,...,7
// flts - 8 by 8 array of floats

// kernel essentially processes large 2D array by looping through slow coordinate
// and having block/thread parallelization of fast coordinate.

__global__ void kernel (int const* inds, float const* flt, ...)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;  // Global fast coordinate
    int idy;                                          // Global slow coordinate
    int sx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;                  // Stride of fast coordinate

    for ( idy = 0; idy < 10000; idy++ )       // Slow coordinate loop
    {
        int id = idx + idy * sx;              // Global coordinate in 2D array

        int ind = inds[id];                   // Index of random access to small array

        float f0 = flt[ind * 8 + 0];
        ...
        float f7 = flt[ind * 8 + 7];

        NEXT I HAVE SOME ALGEBRAIC FORMULAS THAT USE f0, ..., f7
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to access `flt` array?

1. Do not pass `flt`, use `__const__` memory. I am not sure how fast const memory is when different threads access different data.
2. Use as above. Load uniform will not be used because threads access different data. Will it nevertheless be fast because of cache?
3. Copy into shared memory and use shared memory array.
4. Use textures. Never used textures... Can this approach be fast?

For shared memory, it is probably better to transpose `flt` array, i.e. access it this way to avoid bank conflicts:

```
float fj = flt_shared[j * 8 + ind]; // where j = 0, ..., 7
```

PS: Target architectures are Fermi and Kepler.

Comment: So, have you tried using `__constant__` or `__shared__` memory and timing the kernel? `flt` is accessed many times in the kernel. I think `__shared__` memory would give you best performance.

Comment: `__constant__` would be a good choice only if all threads in a warp would access the same value which is not the case here. IMHO the best option here is the use of shared memory containing the transposed data. Please specify what compute architecture are you targeting, it could have an impact.

Comment: So far, I only implemented the case when all values in the `inds` array are 0, so I have no random access and I use `__const__` memory instead of `flt` argunment. BTW, in this case my kernel works faster if compiled with `-dlcm=cg` option. Now I need to extend my kernel to general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" way depends also on the architecture you are working on. My personal experience with random access (your access seems to be sort of a random due to the use of the mapping `inds[id]`) on Fermi and Kepler is that L1 is now so fast that in many cases it is better to keep using global memory instead of shared memory or texture memory.

**Accelerating global memory random access: Invalidating the L1 cache line**

Fermi and Kepler architectures support two types of loads from global memory. **Full caching** is the 
default mode, it attempts to hit in L1, then L2, then GMEM and the load granularity is 128-byte line. **L2-only** attempts to hit in L2, then GMEM and the load granularity is 32-bytes. For certain random access patterns, memory efficiency can be increased by invalidating L1 and exploiting the lower granularity of L2. This can be done by compiling with `–Xptxas –dlcm=cg` option to `nvcc`.

**General guidelines for accelerating global memory access: disabling ECC support**

Fermi and Kepler GPUs support Error Correcting Code (ECC), and ECC is enabled by default. ECC reduces peak memory bandwidth and is requested to enhance data integrity in applications like medical imaging and large-scale cluster computing. If not needed, it can 
be disabled for improved performance using the nvidia-smi utility on Linux (see the [link](http://johanneshabich.blogspot.it/2011/04/nvidia-cuda-disableenable-ecc.html)), or via Control Panel on Microsoft Windows systems. Note that toggling ECC on or off requires a reboot to take effect.

**General guidelines for accelerating global memory access on Kepler: using read-only data cache**

Kepler features a 48KB cache for data that is known to be read‐only for
the duration of the function. Use of the read‐only path is beneficial because it offloads  the Shared/L1 cache path and it supports
full speed unaligned memory access. Use of the read‐only path can be managed automatically by the compiler (use the `const __restrict` keyword) or explicitly (use the `__ldg()` intrinsic) by the
programmer.

Comment: Yes, I am targeting Fermi and Kepler architectures.

Comment: The problem with your advice is that the rest of my kernel (SOME ALGEBRAIC OPERATIONS), which uses coalesced access to several other large arrays of input and output data, actually works faster if compiled with `-dlcm=cg` option.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some other possibilities to speedup the memory access by disabling ECC (for Fermi and Kepler) and by using the read-only data cache (for Kepler).